# What is the exact data type of a spinner in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to write a mortgage calculator app in Android Studio. I use a spinner to choose a length of the mortgage. I want to use the value of the selected item to make some calculation. I want to make a statement to compare the selected item's value to a string variable, but the if statement does not start. 
Should I convert the selected item's type to a string?

```
///adapter for the payment frequency
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
           R.array.paymentFrequency, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); //payment frequency is the name of the string in string.xml
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
frequency.setAdapter(adapter2);

frequency.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              paymentFrequency = String.valueOf(frequency.getSelectedItem());
              Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "choosen year:" + paymentFrequency, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

          @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
              Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "nothing selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
});


public void calculate(View v){

        if (paymentFrequency == "by-weekly"){
            //the number of payment will be multiply by 24
            n = Integer.parseInt(amortizasionPeriod)*24;
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Number of payment:" + n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if ( paymentFrequency == "monthly"){
            //the number of payment will be multiply by 12
            n = Integer.parseInt(amortizasionPeriod)*12;
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Number of payment:" + n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When seeing if two Strings are equivalent in Java you need to use the String.equals(String) method in Java (See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). So instead of the code you have, you should have the following:

```
if (paymentFrequency.equals("by-weekly")) {
    //the number of payment will be multiply by 24
    n = Integer.parseInt(amortizasionPeriod) * 24;
    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Number of payment:" + n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (paymentFrequency.equals("monthly")) {
    //the number of payment will be multiply by 12
    n = Integer.parseInt(amortizasionPeriod) * 12;
    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Number of payment:" + n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```